# How to view an encrypted private key file?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a private key file generated and encrypted by `ssh-keygen`. Is there a way to directly open to view the file when I have the pass phrase? Or is the only method to use `ssh-keygen -p` to undo the pass phrase to get an unencrypted file?

I tried `ssh-keygen -e -f id_rsa`, but it opens up id_rsa.pub even though the file id_rsa contains the private key.

Reason I need the key in the clear is to insert it into Github Actions secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see a way using either `openssl` or `ssh-keygen` to output a decrypted private key. However, it might be possible with an ugly hack like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
pipe=pipe.$$
mkfifo -m600 "$pipe"

(
    cat .ssh/id_rsa >"$pipe"         # Write protected private key to ssh-keygen
    sleep 1
    cat .ssh/id_rsa >"$pipe"         # And again (just because)
    sleep 1

    cat pipe.$$                      # Read the decrypted key
) &

ssh-keygen -q -p -N '' -f "$pipe"    # Decrypt the protected private key

wait
rm -f "$pipe"
```

The decrypted private key should be read from `$pipe` and written to *stdout*, where you can do with it whatever is required.

In writing this code I've assumed that because you've put encryption on your key in the first place you are working in a relatively insecure environment and wouldn't want your key written to disk in an unencrypted format. So I've used a pipe to pass the key around. If you are comfortable with the unencrypted key being saved to disk it's much much easier:

```
cp .ssh/id_rsa .ssh/id_rsa_u
ssh-keygen -q -p -N '' -f .ssh/id_rsa_u
cat .ssh/id_rsa_u
rm .ssh/id_rsa_u
```